# Require Openlayers guide for my requirement

Tags: javascript, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

My Target: Using Openlayers + geoserver + POSTGIS,

1. Display a google map.
2. Dsplay layers from geoserver to the user in a browser ,
3. Allow user to edit features for a layer,
4. Persist the features added newly by the end user to the POSTGIS database

My Status :

1. I could display google map.
2. Loaded SHAPEFILES(.shp) to the POSTGIS DB using postgis shapefile import/export manager
3. Added a workspace in GEOSERVER ADMIN CONSOLE.
4. Added a DATASOURCE in GEOSERVER ADMIN CONSOLE.

MyProblem :

1. unable to  display the layer in browser.
2. Unable to find TYPE GEOMETRY under "Feature Type Details" in EDIT LAYER SCREEN.

**REFERENCES**:

WFS code in a simple HTML page :

```
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("USACITIES",
{
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
        featurePrefix: 'usa', //geoserver worspace name
        featureType: "usa:states", //geoserver Layer Name
        featureNS: "http://usa.opengeo.org", // Edit Workspace Namespace URI
        geometryName: "the_geom" // field in Feature Type details with type "Geometry"
    })
});
map.addLayer(wfs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your code:

```
featureType: "usa:states", //geoserver Layer Name
```

I think this should be

```
featureType: "states", //geoserver Layer Name
```

because the prefix is already defined with the featureNS

As for the "Feature Type Details" in Geoserver:
Check in Postgres if your table has "the_geom" or "geom" coloumn and if its type is geometry.